# Samba 4 (Ubuntu) Administration (Active Directory) via RSAT using Windows 7 error

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, windows-7, samba, samba4

I want to administrate Samba 4 (Active Directory) via RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) using Windows 7. I have installed the RSAT and opened the "Active Directory Computers and Users" tool in Windows 7, but occurs this error:

> Naming information cannot be locate because:
>
> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
>
> Contact your system administrator to verify that your domain is properly
> configured and is currently online.

I am logged in domain using a Domain Administrator User.

When I run `dcdiag` to debug Domain Controller, I get this error:

> {COMPUTERNAME} is not a directory server.
>
> It was not possible locate local server

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

check DNS setting on your win7 machine, check that you could reach at least one domain controller by dns, ip.
I think RSAT failed to contact domain controllers because of DNS issues.

Also try use NETBIOS domain name: domain, and FQDN of the domain controllers.

Comment: The logged Domain Administrator User in Windows 7 gets IP by DHCP, and the DNS and GATEWAY assigned are the same. 

I can ping DNS, GATEWAY, as well FQDN (it is the GATEWAY/SERVER name, and it is the same SERVER that assigns DNS).

Comment: Just to make clear that this solution does not worked. 
Still awaiting other solutions.

Answer (score -1):

An old question, but here is the answer:

Really don't know why my RSAT didn't want to connect on Samba-AD-DC automatically although I was logged as Samba Administrator on my PC, tried so many things but unsuccessful.

Solution was: Open "Active Directory Computers and Users", ignore error and in Action tab choose "Change Domain Controller", enter IP address of your domain controller and that's it.